# Call to function from directive to controller using "&" doesn't send the parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that calls a function in my controller using "&". The invocation works and my function gets executed but the parameters are not send to the function and i get 'undefined'.

**The directive:**

```
angular.module("tiki").directive("inputFile", function(){

return {

    restrict:"A",
    scope:{

        onFile: "&",

    },
    controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){

        var inputFile = $element.find("input")[0]

        $element[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

            inputFile.click()

        })

        inputFile.addEventListener("change", function(e){

            var file = inputFile.files[0]

            var reader = new FileReader()

            reader.addEventListener("load", function(){

                $scope.onFile(reader.result)

            })

            reader.readAsDataURL(file)

        })

    }

}

})
```

**The controller:**

```
angular.module('tiki').controller("tiki.controller.settings.edit", ["$scope", "editTiki", function($scope, editTiki){

    $scope.onFile = function(file){

        console.log(file)

    }

}])
```

The HTML

```
<li input-file on-file="onFile()"><input type="file" style="display:none;"></li>
```

Comment: Are you certain reader.result is not undefined?

Comment: yes, if i add console.log above the function call in the reader.addEventListeren() i get the actual data

Comment: Should it just be on-file="onFile"?

Comment: Brad, yes that's it... make a beautifull answer and i'll check it for you... thx :-)

Comment: Brad sorry, it was actually wrong, i added console.log(reader.result) to the directive and thought that it had outputted the contents in my controller...

Comment: No problem - I'll delete my answer to avoid any confusion...the directive binding article you referenced is a great read.

Answer (score 1):

& is often misunderstood because the primary examples in the angular doc's reference passing functions.  However, what & actually does is add a function to the directive scope that, when called, evaluates the expression against the directive's parent scope and returns the result.  The expression does not have to be a function.  It can be any valid Angular expression.

It is a way to implement one-way binding.

So

```
on-file="onFile(fileObj)"
```

creates this function (note - this is simplified.  The actual implementation is optimized such that $parse isn't called for each invocation of the function):

```
scope.onFile = function(locals) {
    return $parse(attrs.onFile)(scope.$parent, locals);
}
```

Note the "locals" parameter.  This is what enables your second example

```
$scope.onFile({fileObj:reader.result})

{fileObj: reader.result} <---locals
```

When you pass locals to the function returned by $parse, angular replaces any references to those locals that it finds that would be normally attributed to the parent scope with the values in the locals map.

Note that if you didn't pass in locals, and instead just did:

```
$scope.onFile()
```

Then angular would run the parent scope's onFile function and assume that fileObj was either a property of the parent scope or a global object.  If it's neither, it will be undefined in the function.

When you pass just:

```
on-file="onFile"
```

then the result of calling the directive's

```
scope.onFile()
```

method is the parent scope's onFile function, so to invoke the function we just need to pass it data:

```
scope.onFile() === scope.$parent.onFile

scope.onFile()(reader.result)
```

is equivalent to

```
scope.$parent.onFile(reader.result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer was actually this:

**Option 1:**
Send parameters as an object literal.

HTML:

```
<li input-file on-file="onFile(fileObj)"><input type="file" style="display:none;"></li>
```

Directive:

```
            reader.addEventListener("load", function(){

                $scope.onFile({fileObj:reader.result})

            })
```

**Option 2:**
Return a function and invoke it with a parameter list

HTML:

```
<li input-file on-file="onFile"><input type="file" style="display:none;"></li>
```

Directive:

```
        reader.addEventListener("load", function(){

            $scope.onFile()(reader.result)

        })
```

Some reading material:

- https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750
- http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters